# Why computing the DFT from the Ricker Pulse isn't the same as the continuous FT function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, python, fast-fourier-transform

**Question**

I'm trying to use Python's scipy library to compute the DFT of the [Ricker wavelet function](https://subsurfwiki.org/wiki/Ricker_wavelet) and compare it with the analytical Fourier-transformed version of the same function. When I compare the results, they do not match. I want to understand why.

---

Perhaps related, but also unanswered: [DFT is not a sampling of FT?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219951/dft-is-not-a-sampling-of-ft)

---

**Details**

I'm using Python for the experiment. The Ricker pulse function in time domain is defined as follows:

```
def ricker_pulse_time(w0, t):
    return (1. - .5 * w0**2 * t**2) * np.e ** (-.25 * w0**2 * t**2)
```

And, in the frequency domain:

```
def ricker_pulse_freq(w0, w):
    return (2. * w**2) / (np.sqrt(np.pi) * w0**3) * \
        np.e ** (-w**2 / w0**2)
```

As an example, I'm computing the function with 1Hz frequency:

```
hz_to_rad = lambda x: 2. * np.pi * x

w0 = hz_to_rad(1.0) # [Rad/s]
time_step = 1e-6 # [s]
t = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, time_step)
y = ricker_pulse_time(w0, t)
N = len(y)

omega = np.arange(0.0, 40.0, 1e-4)
yy = ricker_pulse_freq(w0, omega)

plt.plot(t, y);
plt.show();
plt.plot(omega, yy);
```

[image: time_domain]

[image: frequency domain]

Finally, to compute the DFT, I'm using scipy's implementation as follows:

```
y_f = fftpack.fft(y)
sample_freq = fftpack.fftfreq(N, d=time_step)
```

And comparing with the analytical solution previously commented:

```
plt.plot(omega, yy, 'r--')
plt.plot(sample_freq[0:N//2], np.abs(y_f[0:N//2]), 'b-')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Rad/s]')
plt.ylabel('y_f')
plt.xlim(0, 40);
plt.show();
```

[image: comparison]

**Question: Why are the results different?**

*Note 1*: I'm only getting half the points, ignoring the negative part of the solution.
*Note 2*: I also tryied scalonating the result using `2/N * abs(y_f)`, but results are also not correct.

[image: comparison 2]

Comment: Honest question. Why do you think that the results should be not different?

Comment: I thought that making the DFT of my function would be a "discrete" version of the "continuous" (analytical) solution. That is, the two curves in the last plot would be the same (or at least very close one to the other). Aren't they suppose to be? I would like to apply `ricker_pulse_freq` in the ifft and get the `ricker_pulse_time` and apply the `ricker_pulse_time` to fft and get `ricker_pulse_freq`. Does my reasoning make any sense?

Comment: Try experimenting with sine waves using FT versus DFT to see if your suppositions are correct.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I managed to make it work.
One problem was that `fft.fftfreq(N, d=time_step)` gives the frequencies in Hz, not in Rad/s, so I had to do `sample_freq = hz_to_rad(fft.fftfreq(N, d=time_step))`
The other problem is the amplitude. I couldn't really get a nice way of retrieving the amplitude correctly, but I know the desired amplitude. So I "fixed" by multiplying by a scale factor using this knowledge (Not the best solution, but works :P)
`scale_factor = np.max(yy)/np.max(y_f_positive)` and `y_f = scale_factor * y_f_positive`

Comment: Possibly duplicated: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115268/what-is-the-relation-between-analytical-fourier-transform-and-dft